# Importing nested struct in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have a framework and a nested struct which I wish to import in my app.

```
open class SomeClass {
    public struct SomeNestedStruct {
         public let someProperty: Int
    }
}
```

The goal is to import only `SomeNestedStruct`. What I have tried so far is

```
import struct MyFramework.SomeClass.SomeNestedStruct
```

The only way around it is to import the whole class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is impossible.

You can import a top level object (`struct`, `enum`, `class`, constant etc) from a module or a submodule. However, you cannot import an inner object.

Answer (score -1):

According to https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Declarations.html#grammar_import-declaration you have to

`import struct MyFramework.SomeClass.SomeNestedStruct`

Comment: I am sorry but this is not quite correct. It is feasible to import classes or structs in swift.

Comment: Yes and this is exactly what I have tried and does not seem to work.

Comment: Don't think it's possible at all with the current Swift version. I checked it trying to import `Row.Animation` from UIKit and `Notification.Name` from Foundation.
Looks like nested types can be imported, only the top nesting type.
By the way, did you try to make a typealias for a nested type?

Comment: @Vladlex Using `typealias` is actually a pretty nice workaround but that means you want the inner type to be used independently and in such case it would be better to make it a top level type.